# Vertically align input + font icon inside div?

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically align an input a font icon inside div. THe icon is slightly larger than the input so its not aligned. I tried vertically-align, but it didn't work.

```
<div>
      <input type="text" class="email-address" 
            value="long-long-long-user@test-test-test.com"> 
             <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

I know this can be done using flex box but wanted to know if I can do it without assign display:flex to outer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed height on the input + icon. Maybe simple try a small amount of negative margin to the top of the icon, or try to align the two elements:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

If you wanted something easy:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-cell` as an alternative:

Quick & dirty example:

```css
.div {
    background-color: #F00;
    padding: 2em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <input type="text" class="email-address" value="long-long-long-user@test-test-test.com"> 
    <span>helldo</span>
</div>
```